# How to adjust a CSS property using a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

### My Problem:

Hey guys. I just have a question regarding changing CSS properties using JavaScript. I want to use an equation I wrote in JavaScript to change the value of a CSS property.

My goal is for the brightness of each element to change based on its distance (in terms of its "zIndex") from the currently selected item.

### What I've Tried:

I've tried declaring variables in CSS, such as "var(--brightness)" for the filter property, but I don't really understand it that well yet so I can't get it to work and I don't even know if that's the correct strategy to use in this case.

I want the selected item's brightness to be 100% and increase the brightness by 30% for every element next to it until it hits the end.

Is anyone able to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

### My Code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="div-items">
            <img class="current-item" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
            <img class="item" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
            <img class="item" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
            <img class="item" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
            <img class="item" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
  --brightness: 1;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}
  
.container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  position: fixed;
  left: -37px;
  top: -37px;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: var(--brightness);
  transition: filter 0.5s;
}
  
.current-item {
  transition: filter 0.5s;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            
var itemClass = items[i].classList
var currentItemIndex = 0;

if (itemClass.contains('current-item')) { // If it is the current item, then this:

    items[i].style.filter = 'brightness(1)'; // Change brightness to 100%
    currentItemIndex = i; // Change current item to this position
                             
    } else if (!itemClass.contains('current-item')) { // If it is not the current item, then this:
        
        var brightness = (100 + (Math.abs(currentItemIndex - i) * 30)) / 100; // Increase by 30% for every position away from current item and assign the float to the variable
        items[i].style.setProperty('--brightness', brightness); // Change the value of "--brightness" to the float assigned to "brightness"
                         
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no need for the CSS variable.
You can directly set the value of the filter property:

```
items[i].filter = "brightness(" + brightness + "%)”;
```

where the variable brightness is the result of your equation.

Comment: You have no idea how hard I'm facepalming right now. I've used that technique so many other times but for some reason, I just never thought about using it in this case. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you a very basic example of setting any CSS property of any HTML element using JavaScript. Let's say you have the following HTML 'div' element with an id 'div1', some text content inside it and you want to style that div according to your need.

```
<div id="div1">I'm HTML</div>
```

Below is the JavaScript code that would basically be used to style this div and the same idea can be applied anywhere in HTML.

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
myDiv.style.color = "yellow";
```

You can still chose to style any other CSS property other than color and you'll be good to go with CSS styling using JavaScript.

Comment: Hey Sharjeel, thanks for the response. I understand how to use JS for basic styling changes such as that, however, I'm trying to change the value of a CSS property using a float that's been assigned to a variable. As far as I'm aware, you cannot change a CSS property using a variable in place of a string such as "100%" with that method.